# Drop foreign key constraint if it doesn't exist

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Part of a script that is run by various customers we support adds foreign keys but one of the foreign keys I don't want to add when running this part of the script because some the customers don't have this in their setup. How do I drop FK6 from the code below. I've tried the DROP on foreign key FK6 below but get syntax errors.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('FK2') IS NULL
BEGIN
ALTER TABLE [table_1] ADD
  CONSTRAINT [FK2] FOREIGN KEY
  (
     [reason_gen]
  ) REFERENCES [table_1] (
     [field_1]
  ) NOT FOR REPLICATION,
  CONSTRAINT [FK3] FOREIGN KEY
  (
     [field_2],
     [field_3]
  ) REFERENCES [table_2] (
     [field_4],
     [field_5]
  ) NOT FOR REPLICATION,
  CONSTRAINT [FK4] FOREIGN KEY
  (
     [res_code_gen]
  ) REFERENCES [table_3] (
     [field_6]
  ) NOT FOR REPLICATION,
  CONSTRAINT [FK5] FOREIGN KEY
  (
     [field_7],
     [field_8]
  ) REFERENCES [table_4] (
     [field_7],
     [field_8]
  ) NOT FOR REPLICATION,

 ALTER TABLE [table_1] DROP
 CONSTRAINT [FK6] FOREIGN KEY
  (
     [field_9]
  ) REFERENCES [ftable_5] (
     [field_10]
  ) NOT FOR REPLICATION
END
```

Comment: if you're dropping a key, you don't need to specify the entire key. e.g. `alter table [table_1] drop constraint [fk6]` would supposedly be all you need...

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for dropping a foreign key is just:

```
ALTER TABLE [table_1] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Which database is this? Oracle, MYSQL, SQL Server?

For Oracle, the syntax is:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
drop CONSTRAINT constraint_name;
```

Comment: It's SQL Server. OK thanks for this but now I have


   ALTER TABLE [table_1] DROP
    CONSTRAINT [FK6] 
    (
     [field_9]
  ) REFERENCES [ftable_5] (
     [field_10]
  ) NOT FOR REPLICATION

And I still get syntax errors for field 9 and field 10. When I hover over each it says 'Incorrect syntax near [field9]. Expect SELECT or '('

Comment: Can anyone help with this please?